# How to bring an image into a python program

Tags: python, image

I am teaching myself Python (early learner) and to test myself, am programming the quadratic equation.  This program takes user inputs as a,b, & c coefficients and calculates the x-intercept, or roots, (if they exist).

I would like to show a picture of a Quadratic / 2nd-degree polynomial x-y graph to the user before they enter their desired coefficients, presumably in a window that could be closed.

I also need to mention I am working in an online compiler so I think specifying image path is tricky.

I poked around a lot, but can't seem to get specifics about how to call an image into the program.

Any help you could provide would be most appreciated.

Comment: Check out [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the module PIL  to open images

```
import Image

def popup():
    filename = "logo.jpg" # Name the file you want to open
    image = Image.open( filename )
    image.show() # Shows the image
```

Link to download the module (not available for 3.x versions yet): http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Answer (score 0):

To import images, you can import cv2 module.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

More details on [cv2](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

Or simpler method is using matplotlib:

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

With imshow() from matplotlib :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = plt.imread(image_file) # read your image file
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off') # clear x- and y-axes
plt.show()
```

The image will pop up, and can be closed by the user and the script will continue.

Hope this helps